# Cygwin stops opening new shells after some time

Tags: windows-10, cygwin

After some use, Cygwin stops opening new shells when I try to open a new window or open a subshell in Midnight Commander (with `^o`).

In MC it prints out:

```
Cannot open master side of pty: No such device or address (6)
```

Opening a new window fails with the window closing immediately.

To fix this, I have to exit all Cygwin windows and start again. Killing `cygserver.exe` or `cygrunsrv.exe` processes is sometimes also necessary.

This is happening for a long time now (at least a few months), but has increased in frequency and happens at least daily, sometimes every hour.

About my installation:

- I'm using `db_home: windows` in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`
- My terminal is fatty, a mintty clone with tabs. The issue seems to happen also with mintty.

Any idea what needs to be fixed?

---

EDIT: Found one more thing, when Cygwin stops to open new shells, it also fails to run [`__git_ps1`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-prompt.sh) that I have in my `PS1` prompt.

Comment: some BLODA interfering ?

Comment: Don't think so, I have nothing in my system from that list and nothing I can think of that could interfere. I have a few things that like to interfere with some apps like te built-in windows antivirus, autohotkey, dropbox or teamviewer (with intergrations disabled) - but I doubt they are the case. Also, please note the edit in my question, @matzeri

Comment: It can be a failed race caused by AV. Difficult to say anyway without a reproducible way to recreate the issue.

Comment: Any idea on how to debug when it happens on my machine? I might be able to find the cause, but have no idea on how to start, @matzeri.